# Azure Search Index field Id an Name

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

First I want to say that the concept of a dedicated search engine is all new to me, so please be indulgent :-)

How does a transactional database entity with an Id and a Name does translate into an Azure Search Index field ?
Should we add only `Name`, or both `Id` and `Name` ?

For example, let's say I want the Client in my index.
I want both to search and have facets on Client.

Should I add only `ClientName` into the index ?
What if `ClientName` is renammed ?
What if `ClientName` is not unique ?

Should I add both fields into the index and have:

- `ClientName`: Searchable
- `ClientId`: Facetable, Filterable

I understand having ClientId Facetable (instead of ClientName) will make it more work to show the facets since i'll have to fetch myself the names corresponding the the ClientId returned by Azure Search.

Also, having the `ClientId` Filterable, I assume it would allow me to perform a batch rename of `ClientName`.

Is my reasoning ok ?

Is there any best practices / guidelines ?

**EDIT**

Here is a more concrete example.
Let say that in the transactional db, we have tables with `Id` and `Name` for `Format`, `Location`, `Author`, `Genre`, `Region`, ...

If we were to build those facets  in Azure Search, would the recommended approach be to add both the `Id` and `Name` for each of them, and set the `Id` field as Facetable ?
[image]

Answer (score 3):

It's probably a good idea to add both Id and Name, since potentially Name can change. Also, the Name field can contain arbitrary characters, while document id can only contain alphanumeric characters, dashes, underscores and equal signs (see [Naming Rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/Naming-rules)).

Only id field must be unique (it has the same semantics as the primary key in a relational database). All other fields can have non-unique values. If a value changes, you just update the document (using `merge` or `mergeOrUpload` indexing action).

Azure Search supports batches of up to 1000 documents. If you want to update more documents than that, you'll have to break your updates into multiple batches. See [Indexing API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/addupdate-or-delete-documents). The links shows REST API, but of course the same functionality is available in .NET SDK, if you're on .NET.

> Should I add both fields into the index and have:
>   ClientName: Searchable
>   ClientId: Facetable, Filterable
>   I understand having ClientId Facetable (instead of ClientName) will make it more work to show the facets since i'll have to fetch myself the names corresponding the the ClientId returned by Azure Search.

We do not recommend making `ClientId` facetable. Facets work best on fields with a relatively small number of unique values. Since `ClientId` by definition must be unique, faceting will not be useful and any faceting queries that reference `ClientId` will probably perform poorly if you have many documents in your index. It is reasonable to make `ClientId` filterable though, since there may be situations when you want to retrieve or exclude certain documents by `ClientId`.

> Also, having the ClientId Filterable, I assume it would allow me to perform a batch rename of ClientName.

This is not necessary. Making `ClientId` filterable allows you to filter by `ClientId`, nothing more. You always need to specify document IDs when updating fields using the Index API, but that doesn't require the ID field to be filterable.

I hope this gets you started, and as you have more specific questions, you can post them here.

Comment: Thanks Eugene, this definitely helps. I edited my question with a more concrete example, since I'm not sure about your mention of Naming Rules, I am not talking about document key here.

Comment: Hi Guillaume, your edits look as though you would need to be able to support hierarchical facets.  There is a really good technique on how to handle this which you can read about [here](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/onsearch/2015/09/09/multi-level-taxonomy-facets-in-azure-search/).  Please let us know if this does not work for you or if I misunderstood you.

Comment: No, no multi-level, but thanks for the link, this is great! My question is how would we keep the index updated when changes are made in the real database ie: ProductCategory.Name is renamed, ProductModel.Name is renamed, new Products added to a model, etc ? I assume we need ids like ProductCategoryId, ProductId, etc into the index ?

Comment: If you want to move data from Azure SQL into Azure Search, consider using [Azure SQL indexer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-howto-connecting-azure-sql-database-to-azure-search-using-indexers), in particular [tracking changes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-howto-connecting-azure-sql-database-to-azure-search-using-indexers#capturing-new-changed-and-deleted-rows). You don't really need to store IDs in the search index - just store what's necessary for your search scenarios + document key.